# Python path setting error with manage.py

Tags: python, django

When I run ./manage.py, I get the following error,

from: can't read /var/mail/os.path

./manage.py: line 4: import: command not found

./manage.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `0,'

./manage.py: line 7: `sys.path.insert( 0, abspath( join( dirname( **file** ), 'external_apps' ) ) )'

What is it!!! How can I resolve it?

Comment: What happens when you run `python ./manage.py` ?  if it works, then you just need to add something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` to manage.py as the first line.

Comment: try `which python` and substitute the output of that. e.g. `#!/bin/python` or something to that effect.

Comment: /usr/bin/python It is the output! I added #!/usr/bin/python python. Then I ran sudo bash ./manage.py. But still same problem!

Comment: why are you running `sudo bash ./manage.py`?  it's python code, you should run it with `python`, not `bash`.  And be careful with `sudo`.

Comment: You mean I should run python ./manage.py ?

Comment: Yes.  All of those commands are not found because you are running it as a bash script instead of a python script.  They don't exist in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add #!/usr/bin/python . Use virtualenv and activate it before running python manage.py your_command . When you will be familiar with virtualenv try virtualenvwrapper.